# onItemClick doesn't work when onItemLongClick is present (in ListView)

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `ListView` where i want to trigger different actions depending if the user made a short or a long click. Unfortunately, after adding the listener for the long click, the short one will never be called.

If i do a short click, nothing happens. If a i do a long click, the corresponding method is called. I have Android 4.2.2.

How can i solve the problem, i.e. make the short click work?

My code:

Class declaration:

```
public class ContactListFragment extends Fragment implements
      LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener
```

Attaching the listeners:

```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
      mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_contacts);
      // Gets a CursorAdapter
      mCursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.contact_list_item, null, FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS, 0);
      // Sets the adapter for the ListView
      mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
      // Set the item longclick listener to be the current fragment.
      mContactsList.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
      // Set the item click listener to be the current fragment.
      mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   }
```

The listeners themself:

```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
         long id) {
      Log.i(ContactListFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "Short click detected.");
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
      Log.i(ContactListFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "Long click detected.");
      return false;
   }
```

The XML (`contact_list_item.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:longClickable="true"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

([Android GridView OnItemLongClick listener called after OnItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708068/android-gridview-onitemlongclick-listener-called-after-onitemclick) doesn't apply as i'm not interested in a context menu.)

Comment: Why are you doing this... `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_contacts)`? That indicates the `ListView` is part of the `Activity` content view but (from your code) you're trying to handle click events within a `Fragment` attached to that `Activity`.

Comment: `findViewById()` is undefined in the `Fragment` class. Therefore, i have to get the activity. `list_contacts` is inside the fragment XML (and the fragment is included with `<fragment android:id="@+id/contact_list_fragment" .... />` in the activity XML.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the `Activity` context returned by `getActivity()` in order to call `findViewById(...)`. Simply use the `View` you create in `onCreatView(...)` and call its `findViewById(...)` method. Alternatively you can do this in the `onViewCreated(...)` method which receives the `View` created by `onCreatView(...)` as a parameter.

Comment: Changed, but it didn't solve the problem with the short clicks doing nothing.